# Extending AppWidget to Wearable App

Tags: android, widget, wear-os

I have basic Android widgets which are already running well on phone. How to extend it to Android Wear devices?

1. Should I be able to extend it somehow? So only 1 source code for both phone and wear devices.
2. Or I must implement a new project for Android wear devices?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can extend wear app support just one application.(You not have to upload other Wear application at Play Store.

Add wear module in your project by Android studio. (File -> New Module -> Android Wear Module)

Maybe this site can help you to build wear app.
https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/creating.html

Comment: Ok thanks. Is it must be using Android Studio? Or Eclipse can do?

Comment: You can use Eclipse too.. but it's more harder than Android Studio to developing Android wear app. And google does not support Eclipse ADT anymore.. So I Recommend to use Android Studio strongly.

Comment: How actually step by step extending AppWidget to Wearable? File-New Module->Android Wear will definitely create a new module not extending Wear functionality to current App Widget module.

Comment: Wear module not extending phone application module. That is another app. You should devlelop your application for wear also. If you want develop watchface check here https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/watch-faces/index.html of just for wear app you can develop same as phone module on the wear module.(Same as Android Activity)

Comment: So is it actually 1 module that runs both AppWidget and Wear App? Or they must separate? Sorry I couldn't understand your comment clearly.

Comment: must be separate. wear app is another app from phone app.